# GAE can't serve my image

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I need help fixing the following error when I run my webapp:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet WARNING: 
    No file found for: /images/banner.jpg
```

I've already setup the config file to include that folder in web-inf:

```
<static-files>
     <include path="/images/**.jpg" />   
</static-files>
```

I am using Spring 2.5 btw for my project but I have already set the url mapping in the dispatcher servlet for my spring beans only and not "/" so that the request for the image goes back to the server:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>hardwire</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/web</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My directory structure in war folder looks like

web-inf/

- account/ <-- where all my jsps are
- images/
- etc

Comment: I presume the "static-files" is in web.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(sigh) I finally resolved my issue after much googling. Turns out the httpserver looks for the images outside the WEB-INF folder. X)